# How to set up a 100 nodes kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

From the [performance test report](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2015/09/kubernetes-performance-measurements-and.html) we can find that the `kubernetes` can support 100 nodes.

To do the same test, I have set up a 100 nodes `kubernetes` cluster, but the `kube-apiserver` became slow when the cluster is set up. That meant when I typed `kubectl get nodes`, it suspended and can not get any respond.

To find the reason, I chech the connections of `kube-apiserver` and found there were about 660+ ESTABLISHED connections on port 8080 (I used the insecure port of apiserver), and when I stop some(about 20) slaves, the `apiserver` recovered common. So I thought the reason for `kube-apiserver` becoming slow is the too large concurrency.

So I am wonder how the Google set up a 100 nodes cluster? Is there something wrong in my work?

PS: The `--max-requests-inflight` of `kube-apiserver` has been set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc you link to describes the methodology used (specifically the master VM size). The cluster is created in Google Compute Engine using the default cluster/kube-up.sh script from the repository, with all the default settings implied by that.

How large is the master that you're using? If it's really small, it's possible that it could struggle with a lot of nodes and pods.

Comment: ok, thanks for your patient. I have also thought about the hardware performance of master as you said, but what I really want to know is whether Google used some load balancing components like `nginx` in front of `apiserver`...

Comment: Like Alex said, the test was done with the standard kube-up.sh script, which doesn't configure any load balancer in front of the apiserver. Instead, it just uses a more powerful machine to run the master components.

Answer (score 0):

That's what is used to make cluster and from that govern it using kubernetes

```
def make_cluster(CID, mach_type, nof_machs, ZID):
    """
    Given machine type and # of machines, creates cluster

    Parameters
    ------------

    CID: string
        cluster id

    mach_type: string
        machine type

    nof_machs: integer
        number of machines

    ZID: string
        zone id

    returns: integer
        return code from gcloud call
    """

    cmd = "gcloud container clusters create {0} --machine-type {1} --zone {3} --num-nodes {2}".format(CID, mach_type, nof_machs, ZID)

    rc = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    return rc
```